# Find in html where element attribute contains string selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website that has a bit of html in this format.

```html
</p></div><div class="content "><ul class="office-list"><li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="_office atlanta" data-slug="atlanta" data-title="Atlanta" data-address="Twilio Atlanta<br />950 East Paces Ferry Road NE, 18th Floor<br />Atlanta, GA 30326<br />"
```

I have tried using some python code which is:

```py
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'address')]")
    for item in items:
        addresses.append(item.text)
```

However in this case, its not the class which contains `'address'`, it is `data-address`. How can I search any element attribute which contains `'address'`?

Comment: IMO, the `<a>` tag is still incomplete. Which text are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Guy has handled this for me fantastically. I'm wanting to extract 
`Twilio Atlanta 950 East Paces Ferry Road NE, 18th Floor Atlanta, GA 30326`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `name()` function

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//@*[contains(name(),'address')]/..")
```

The text you are looking for is in the attribute. Since you know only part of the name you need to use JavaScript to get it

```
value = driver.execute_script(
'for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) {
   if (arguments[0].attributes[index].name.includes("address")) {
     return arguments[0].attributes[index].value;
   }
}', element)
```

Comment: My issue is the next page I scrape may not contain `data-address` but `registered-address`. Only `address` is consistent.

Comment: I get this error:

```python

WebDriverException: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Attr data-address="Twilio Atlanta<br />950 East Paces Ferry Road NE, 18th Floor<br />Atlanta, GA 30326<br />"]
```

Comment: @Jack add `/..` at the end (see answer).

Comment: Fantastic! This is great! 

Any idea why, when I use this list comp, I am not getting the full address but only `Twilio Atlanta`? 

```    
addresses = [address.get_attribute("innerHTML") for address in other_items]
```

Comment: @Jack What is `other_items`?

Comment: web_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//@*[contains(name(),'address')]//..")
    addresses = []
    addresses = [address.get_attribute("text") for address in web_elems]

The text returned is not from the element which contains 'address'. It is using another part of the Web Element.